# Get the hostname/IP:port of the server to which the request is to be forwarded from Zuul+ribbon

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul, netflix-ribbon

I'm using Eureka for service discovery and Zuul+ribbon as reverse proxy and load balancer. 
I have 2 instances registered under Eureka as follows:

```
MYSERVICE   n/a (2) (2) UP (2) - MYHOST:MyService:8888 , MYHOST:MyService:9999
```

Below is my zuul config:

```
@EnableZuulProxy
@EnableDiscoveryClient

zuul:
  debug.request: true
  sensitiveHeaders: 
  routes:
ecm:
   path: /myservice/**
   serviceId: MYSERVICE
   stripPrefix: false
  host:
       maxTotalConnections: 200
       maxPerRouteConnections: 30
  RibbonRoutingFilter:
       route.disable: false
```

I want a filter or interceptor which would help me log my request URL, my request params and the server chosen by Zuul.

I tried extending the following:

```
@Component
public class RibbonInterceptor extends ZoneAvoidanceRule {

@Override
public Server choose(Object key) {

Server choose = super.choose(key);
System.out.println(choose);
return choose;
}
```

But, this just gave me the server info from Ribbon, and here ribbon was just choosing a server. I wanted this info from Zuul along with the request details.

Please help!!

Comment: Have you tried creating a Zuul `post` filter? there might be information on which endpoint was chosen, perhaps in the headers even

Comment: Zuul filter does not expose ribbon related things in detail. Already tried by implementing PRE, ROUTE & POST filters.

Answer (score 1):

For the request URL and the server chosen by Zuul, you can set the loglevel of the `LoadBalancerContext` to `DEBUG` in application.properties.

```
#logging load balancing information 
logging.level.com.netflix.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerContext=DEBUG
```

This will create a log statement like:

```
2017-09-11T12:59:09.746-07:00: [DEBUG] hystrix-myserviceV3-2 com.netflix.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerContext - myserviceV3 using LB returned Server: myservice-2.abc.com:8080 for request http:///myservice/auth/users
```

Not sure though, how you can handle the request params.

Comment: This would just print out in the log file. I need an actual interceptor kinda thing just after the server is selected along with the request object.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use Apache HttpClient, there are many ways to do this but I think the most simple is to add an `HttpRequestInterceptor` to the `CloseableHttpClient` used by Ribbon. You can customize the client by providing a bean of type `CloseableHttpClient` as mentioned in the documentation [1]. You then have the request actually used by HttpClient so you log the details.

```
@Bean
public HttpClient delegate(IClientConfig clientConfig)
{
    HttpClientBuilder builder = HttpClientBuilder.create();
    //set connection pool configuration

    HttpRequestInterceptor interceptor = (request, context) -> logger.info("Server : {}, headers : {}", request.getRequestLine().getUri(), request.getAllHeaders());
    builder.addInterceptorFirst(interceptor);

    return builder.build();
}
```

---

You could also extend `HttpClientRibbonCommand` and override the `run()` method to print what you want. You would use your new class by providing a bean of type `RibbonCommandFactory<YourExtendedRibbonCommand>` and it should wire automatically to the `RibbonRoutingFilter`.

---

Finally, if you're using the semaphore isolation strategy in hystrix, you could use your `RibbonInterceptor` like you indeed in addition to `com.netflix.zuul.context.RequestContext`. In the `RequestContext`, you'll find the original `HttpServletRequest` along with parsed parameters and headers that were processed in the `pre` filters.

---

[1] https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/single/spring-cloud-netflix.html#_zuul_http_client

Comment: I haven't tried this. Will try and pos an update asap. Thanks :)

Comment: Can you please list the other possible ways to do this too?